# Formulas in VBA that include variables

Tags: vba, excel

Can't quite figure out how best to google this but I have been stuck on it for quite a while now.

I am trying to automate the retrieval of statistics from a weekly report and each report downloaded is given a different sheet name, week 11 for example is known as 'Week 11' rather than Sheet1.

My formula that works for a single week works, but how can I replace 'Week 11.csv' with the variable week & ".csv"?

```
Cells(Range("A2"), 2).Value = [COUNTIFS('Week 11.csv'!$J:$J,B$2&"*",'Week 11.csv'!$K:$K,"NC recd*")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Evaluate("COUNTIFS(week & "".csv""!$J:$J,B$2&"" * "",week & "".csv""!$K:$K,""NC recd*"")")
```

Solved my issue, literally the last thing I tried!

Comment: If this works for you, please mark it as the correct answer.